# How do I connect via FTP to XAMPP (on Mac)?

Tags: xampp

How do I connect via FTP to XAMPP (on Mac)?

I need to change CHMOD Permission issues on Localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an FTP client like FileZilla:

http://filezilla-project.org/

...provided that FTP service is running on your instance if XAMPP and the ports are open.

Comment: Yeah, you are supposed to connect with 127.0.0.1 Username: Nobody, Password: xampp

Comment: I'm a Mac user and I can't connect my xampp server with FileZilla although the configurations settings are right.. (host: localhost or 192.168.1.18; port: 21; pass: ***; user: nobody;) why?